# SQL script through bat file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, automation, sqlplus

I am trying to automatize some daily checks and now I need to use SQL query.
So I write my SQL script and then tried to run it through batch file to be able to put it to task scheduler.

So I wrote something like this

```
sqlplus user/pw@DBServer @PathToSQLScript.sql > "DestinationWhereToPutOutput"
```

It is confusing me because this works normally at any other server that I already automatized but at this one it gave me error

> ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

And wanting me to reenter credentials.

Is there any other way how to run SQL script through batch file?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent reason for ORA-12154 is that *DBServer* can't be found in TNSNAMES.ORA file. Therefore:

- create DBServer's alias in TNSNAMES.ORA, or
- use EZCONNECT syntax (which doesn't require TNSNAMES.ORA) that looks like `host:port/service_name`

  For example, that would be

  ```
  sqlplus user/pw@db_server:1521/orcl
  ```

---

For much more info about troubleshooting ORA-12154, see [Ed Stevens' blog](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help it seems to be working just fine with your solution.